# Google OAuth not working on iOS

Tags: oauth2-playground

Trying to get my head around OAuth 2.0. I am building a cross platform google drive app using PhoneGap Build and JQM.

I am able to format the request URL correctly and on both iOS and Android. It prompts the user for ID/PW using InAppBrowser (tried child browser too). Next user gets prompt with blue button on web page to "Allow Access" just like on other google web sites/apps. On Android all is well user taps allow access and callback finds the success code and I can grab the token. On iOS I get a "Load Error" message in the status bar of InAppBrowser but I can't trap the error to see what it is. It seems as if the redirect parameter breaks things before the startLoad or endLoad event can be called to trap success/failure in the response from Google.

Playing with oauth2-playground my URL looks correct and like I said it is working fine on Android.

Anyone have any ideas what differences I need to look at with regard to iOS? Been stumped here for a couple of days. Any and all help greatly appreciated.

I have tried redirecting back to http//localhost and http//localhost/afterOauth.html where afterOauth.html is a page in the app to give the redirect something to call the startLoad/endLoad event.

**Update**: I really think the problem has something to do with the redirect I give the original Google request. If I change "localhost" to urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob which shows up in the google documentation both Android and iOS behave the same. They take me to a page saying "Please copy this code, switch to your application and paste it there" With the code=4/MyCode below it.

Also, I added a loaderror callback. It does not fire on Android but does on iOS giving error code -1004 and error message: could not connect to the server. However in the event.url of this loaderror it clearly shows the code=4/myCode. What is the missing link here for iOS and successful OAuth between Google?

Comment: Please see additional information with thoughts on redirect

Comment: Have you had any success with this? I've tried to use Ajax to get the request, so I can parse the title (which apparently contains the code), but it's not working.